# Trouble installing stl_tools on Windows 10

Tags: python, module, pip, windows-10, visual-studio-2019

Hello I tried to download the package stl_tools in python (3.8.2) (Windows 10)  in order to process .jpg images and convert them to .stl for 3D printing.
I typed `pip install stl_tools` and there was an error saying that:

```
Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
```

As a solution I downloaded Visual Studio 2019 Desktop development with C++ with all the recommended features: picture[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJZ6l.png)

-MSVC v142 - VS 2019 C++ x64/x86 build tools (v14.28)

-Windows 10 SDK (10.0.18362.0)

-Just-In-Time debugger

-C++ profiling tools

-C++ CMake tools for Windows

-C++ ATL for latest v142 build tools (x86 & x64)

-Test Adapter for Boost.Test

-Test Adapter for Google Test

-Live Share

-C++ AddressSanitizer (Experimental)

I attempted again `pip install stl_tools`  to Windows 10 PowerShell
and another error appeared namely:

```
ERROR: Failed building wheel for stl-tools

      Running setup.py clean for stl-tools
    Failed to build stl-tools
    Installing collected packages: stl-tools
        Running setup.py install for stl-tools ... error
```

I don’t know where is the problem and why this package can not be downloaded. I checked if wheel module exists and it is already installed in my PC.
Any help will be valuable.

Thank you in advance for your time .

Comment: I am also facing same issue. Did you get solution for this issue?

Comment: I am able to fix issue by modifying VS installation (include c++) and running "pip install stl_tools" command using administrator rights.